# PyZMQ prompting windows to ask for network access on Windows even without anything other than IPC

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using PyZMQ for IPC (over TCP) on Windows 10, as part of an automated updater. I have noticed that on some computers, a firewall prompt appears to select if it can use public or private internet, despite the fact that it makes no connections to the internet - only to localhost.

This PyInstaller-packaged script is launched by a user-land script.

So:
    Script launches my PyInstaller-packaged script->
    Script uses pyzmq strictly to connect to localhost->
    Windows prompts how it should be allowed through firewall

This prompt doesn't stop the program, but I don't want users to see that and wonder what virus they might have.

This is the code that supposedly triggers it:

```
sckt = self.zmq_context.socket(zmq.REQ)
sckt.connect('tcp://localhost:%s' % updater_shared_port)
```

Is there anything I can do to stop that pop-up from Windows Firewall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there is something:

may implement the connection by some other than **`tcp://`** transport class.

ZeroMQ can help you build your ideas via smart transports`{ ipc:// | inproc:// | vmci:// }` given you need not assemble/disassemble the full-height-L3-ISO-OSI stack to reach a counterparty, hosted on the same **`localhost`**.

Comment: I know :-( I hate that. hey bazza, know any similar alternatives with Python bindings? in terms of extreme ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall could be configured to allow your programmes to run unhindered. That might be a nuissance to do by hand. There's probably a way to have an installer configure the firewall appropriately, but that'll be a ton of work to set up.

On the off-chance that it's the binding end that's the causing the pop up (not the connecting end as you suggest), apparently one can bind a zmq socket to a particular interface. This is done with a connection string such as `zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");` This will clamp the socket to the loopback, which may well not trouble the firewall at all. `zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://*:5555)` will open a socket on all interfaces, including any Internet facing interfaces, which should certainly grab the attention of the firewall. If you've not already tried that, might be worth a quick go.

Comment: +1 I'll try binding to specific interfaces and get back to you, but it may be a bit. I won't forget though

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave - you haven't got back yet